# Como saber cual es el pixel central de una imagen

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Como se si el pixel X,Y es el pixel central

1.-Tengo el siguiente código, que manualmente e metido el pixel, el tamaño del imagview es de         android:layout_width="400dp",android:layout_height="400dp".

```
    BitmapDrawable drawable =(BitmapDrawable)imgviewtomarfoto.getDrawable();
    Bitmap bitmap= drawable.getBitmap();

    int colour = bitmap.getPixel(200, 200);

    int red = Color.red(colour);
    int blue = Color.blue(colour);
    int green = Color.green(colour);
    int alpha = Color.alpha(colour);
    txtviewcolor1.setText("R: "+red+","+" G: "+green+","+" B: "+blue);
```

Comment: Solamente entendí la pregunta *Como saber cual es el pixel central de una imagen*. Dado que las imágenes son rectangulares, encontrar el centro es lo mismo que encontrar el centro de un rectángulo. De los demás detalles no entendí cuál es la pregunta, o qué tienen que ver con la pregunta que hiciste. ¿Puedes clarificar por favor?

Comment: Realmente esto son dos preguntas en una. ¿Podrías editar esta pregunta para que quede solo la pregunta sobre el centro de la imagen y crear una pregunta nueva para el tema del RGB? Aquí se explican los motivos por los que se debería evitar hacer múltiples preguntas en una: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5006/modularicemos-las-preguntas-para-que-se-pregunte-una-sola-cosa-y-resulte-%c3%batil-pa